# Cannot kill python program on port 8000 causing Tryton server socket.error

Tags: sockets, localhost, gnu

I have been getting more deeply involved in python for scientific computing (as a hobby) over the last 2 years and as I also have a medical degree, I really, really want to get a copy of GNU Health running on my new Kubuntu 15.10 OS so I can learn how it all works and play around with it! I followed the instructions to install it on this page: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GNU_Health/Installation

I got pretty much to the end but when I try to launch the tryton server with `./trytond` I get this error message:

```
[Thu Oct 29 10:25:02 2015] INFO:trytond.server:using /home/gnuhealth/gnuhealth/tryton/server/config/trytond.conf as configuration file
[Thu Oct 29 10:25:02 2015] INFO:trytond.server:initialising distributed objects services
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./trytond", line 80, in <module>
    trytond.server.TrytonServer(options).run()
  File "/home/gnuhealth/gnuhealth/tryton/server/trytond-3.4.6/trytond/server.py", line 71, in run
    self.start_servers()
  File "/home/gnuhealth/gnuhealth/tryton/server/trytond-3.4.6/trytond/server.py", line 178, in start_servers
    self.jsonrpcd.append(JSONRPCDaemon(hostname, port, ssl))
  File "/home/gnuhealth/gnuhealth/tryton/server/trytond-3.4.6/trytond/protocols/jsonrpc.py", line 382, in __init__
    self.server = server_class((interface, port), handler_class, 0)
  File "/home/gnuhealth/gnuhealth/tryton/server/trytond-3.4.6/trytond/protocols/jsonrpc.py", line 317, in __init__
    bind_and_activate)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 420, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/home/gnuhealth/gnuhealth/tryton/server/trytond-3.4.6/trytond/protocols/jsonrpc.py", line 346, in server_bind
    SimpleJSONRPCServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 434, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

On further investigation with `sudo netstat -pant | grep 8000` I get

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2516/python
```

I have tried to kill this python program running on port 8000 every different way I could find but it keeps coming back with a new number in front i.e.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      916/python
```

I kill it then...

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      some_other_number etc../python
```

Can someone please explain what is going on with this python program keeping on restarting and how I fix this one little problem getting in the way of me starting the server!?

Comment: If it helps I also had the latest anaconda installed prior to beginning the installation. So I could try fully uninstalling anaconda tomorrow... I still wonder though if it it something to do with how the gnu health system is configured?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at the install instructions you mentioned.

Look at this section:

> Activate Network Devices for the JSON-RPC Protocol
>
> The Tryton GNU Health server listens to localhost at port 8000, not allowing direct connections from other workstations.
>
> editconf
>
> You can edit the parameter listen in the [jsonrpc] section , to activate the network device so workstations in your net can connect. For example, the following block
>
> [jsonrpc]
>   listen = *:8000
>
> will allow to connect to the server in the different devices of your system.

Check if you can change the value of the port and see if it works.

Use a port number that is unused. Use this command to check whether the port number is available. It has to be greater than 1024.

```
netstat -nlp | grep <self-chosen-hopefully-unused-port-number>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this got the server running yesterday! I have since been having endless errors to get the tryton client working though. Finally followed up a goose chase of about 4-5 different dependencies which all had erorrs of their own... and got the tryton client running as well as the server and then....the server was version 3.4.x and the client was 3.6.x so could not connect! Then I thought that it should be as simple as going back to an older client but then everything broke again! I think i'm giving up. I have hurrendous eye strain from the last 3 days of trying after work.

Comment: Gnu Health support is somewhat outdated on Debian / Ubuntu branch. One way to deal is to stay conservative and install older packages manually. But you will get outdated software in the long run. The other option is to quit "you fav distribution packaging" way and switch to "python / virtualenv / etc" way but that will be more demanding. If you haven't quit hope - stay connected.

Comment: @HaydenDonnelly, Can I ask you to accept my answer by clicking the tick mark if it helped you?

Comment: Looks like @HaydenDonnelly treats stackoverflow as disposable means without any mutual effort.